# Getting contextstack overflow error - too many nested ifelse statements within for loop?

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I currently have a for loop that iterates over each row checking for multiple conditions being true between rows (the next and current row) and within the same row.  I am getting an Error: contextstack overflow.
I have a bunch of nested ifelse statements (too many) and was wondering how people reduce the number of ifelse statements they use when there are a lot of possible combinations of conditions to check. Do you break this up into multiple loops? 
I see a few ways where I can segment the date into groupings and have ifelse statements within the groupings (so would this be an if statement with ifelse statements nested?) but I am not sure if that will help me get rid of the error I am getting.

```
for (i in 1 : length(df$id)-1){ ifelse(many conditions, do this, ifelse(many conditions, do this,    ifelse(many conditions, do this, ...... ifelse(many conditions, do this, xxxxx) }
```

So I am essentially iterating over each row because I need to compare within each row and against the previous row. The main problem is I seem to reach the maximum number of ifelse statements allowed to be nested. Is there a way to better group this to reduce that limiting factor because right now mine are all nested. Can I have 5 if statements (one of my many criteria is actually a 5 level cateogry) and then nest ifelse statements within those with other criteria so the loop does not evaluate every ifelse statement? Is that viable in R?

Comment: So the problem is readability or the error you're getting? Also, please provide a coding example.

Comment: The problem is the error I am getting which I believe is due to exceeding the maximum number of ifelse statements in R? I will try to post a code example but I could potentially have hundreds of scenarios which wont process.

Comment: I believe this is a matter of preference for cleanliness. Example: for me if I had a few conditions for a variable that I want to check I would either stack them all into one if statement if possible: `if(x >5 & x < 10){do}` for example. or do the negative and break the loop, for example if you want >5: `if(x < 5){next}` which will keep your code more flat, and in my opinion, more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookup table if it's categorical:

```
> df = data.frame(x=1:5, y=letters[1:5])
> df
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 4 d
5 5 e

> z=c("a", "c", "d")
```

The slow nested way:

```
> ifelse(z == "a", 1, ifelse(z=="b", 2, ifelse(z=="c", 3, ifelse(z=="d", 4,ifelse(z=="e", 5, NA)))))
[1] 1 3 4
```

The faster R way:

```
> df$x[sapply(z, function(x) which(x==df$y))]
[1] 1 3 4
```

If it's numeric, you can use `cut` instead:

```
> z = c(1.1, 2.23)
> df$y[cut(z, df$x)]
[1] a b
```